# rewrite ViewGroup onMeasure, child match_parent not work

Tags: android, viewgroup, onmeasure

I have a custom Relativelayout with custom `onMeasure` method. code as below.

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int height = (int) (getMeasuredWidth() * ratio);
        measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), height);
    }
```

The purpose of above code is to set `height=width*ratio`.

After doing that.  Child view with `layout_height` value `match_parent` will not be  fill the parent's height. It works like `wrap_content`.

```
    <com.baidu.mall.ui.view.RatioRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        app:riv_ratio=".615384615">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selected_item_grid_item0_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </com.baidu.mall.ui.view.RatioRelativeLayout>
```

And I debug the `measuredHeight` and `height` of child view. I found they are not equal. It is strange.

I want to know what's wrong with my code. And how I can fix it?